# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) - XAMPP Mac OSX

Tags: mysql, macos, sockets, xampp

How to fix MySQL not starting in XAMPP for Mac OSX?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by reinstalling XAMPP like so:

**1. Uninstall** XAMPP using the unistaller found at `/Applications/XAMPP/uninstall.app`,

**2. Delete** the leftovers from  `/Applications/XAMPP/`,
(backup `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs` and databases if necessary) then

**3. Install** XAMPP using installer again.

Afterwards, the missing mysql.sock and proper links to it are back to normal and `$ mysql` works.

Comment: Can you just copy the DBs as files? I thought that you cannot

Answer (score 4):

This seems like mysql isn't running at all. Try this in terminal and try again :

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

Comment: MySQL can't start.

Comment: I meant the mysql damon. Is it running (mysqld)? What you're trying to run is the mysql command line client, which needs the mysql server running. 

Run this command in Terminal. Do you see MySQL in the list? 

`netstat -atp tcp | grep -i "listen"`

Comment: How to make it auto start on boot on mac ?

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this issue multiple times on OSX I believe it is something to do with an error during installation.

There are a few potential points of failure:

1. The first is checking your configuration files point to the correct location of your socket file. To check this Open your /etc/my.cnf file and check/edit these two configurations.

   `[mysqld] socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock`

   `[client] socket=/var/mysql/mysql.sock`
2. If this doesn't work it could also be that the correct access
   privileges have not been granted to the files during installation.

   You can try to change the ownership of the files like so:

   ```
   sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/var/mysql
   ```
3. Another potential point of failure is that an error file has become
   inaccessible or corrupted so its worth stopping your server deleting
   it and then starting your server again.

   Check in directory /usr/local/var/mysql for a file which is named
   (your-computer-name).local.err if it is owned my _mysql (or similar)
   delete it and then try start the server again with `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried your steps, it's still not working. Still Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket ...

Answer (score 0):

In MacOS:

Step 1:
Go to your Finder and edit the file as the following path below. `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf`

Step 2:
Open the file and find the [mysqld] section add one line as following `innodb_force_recovery = 1` ,and save.

Step 3: Run command in your Terminal 
`sudo /Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql.server start` 
Wait until everything is OK.

Step 4: Edit the my.cnf again and remove the line you just added `innodb_force_recovery = 1` ,and save.

Step 5: Stop for restart `sudo /Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql.server stop`
 Wait until everything is OK.

**Remind** that if you didn’t passed this step your all tables will be read only.

Step 6: Open XAMPP Manager and click “Start” button to start MySQL Database again The progressing status will show “Running”.

**NOTE**: This problem will be faced again after you restart your Mac OS X. So, you have to repeat these steps again. Remember that this is the workaround solution.

[source](https://www.areyoucodingenough.com/query-technics-database/solution-mysql-database-doesnt-start-xampp-mac-os-x/)